# Drag Drop using SendMessage

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, sendmessage

This sounds funny..just a little experiment.
i wanted to simulate a drag drop of a file on a Application/Window using Send Message.
Is it possible?

I dont have code for the application but on the executable.

The application is [IP Messenger](http://www.ipmsg.org/index.html.en).

What i wanted to do is use "Send To" functionality to send the file to an .exe ,which will
find IPMessenger window and simulate a drag drop thr code.

The user will select the file and right click "send to" to the .exe which will do drag drop from code.

**Note: IP Messenger supports drag-drop operation for files

thx
amit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [`WM_DROPFILES` Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774303%28VS.85%29.aspx). I guess that you could use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28VS.85%29.aspx) to locate the window that is IP Messenger and then build the `DROPFILES` structure to send with the `WM_DROPFILES` message.

The final link would be to Codeproject, with some help on creating the `DROPFILES` structure: [How to Implement Drag and Drop Between Your Program and Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorerdragdrop.aspx).

---

Instead of using `CreatToolhelp32Snapshot` you could be using [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Here you will get the `HWND` for IP Messenger directly, instead of `CTh32S`, which will only locate the `HANDLE` for the process.

When this is done you create the `DROPFILES` structure. Read the comments on the CodeProject link in the *"Initiating a drag and drop"* section for more info of how.

And finally you send it with sendmessage

```
SendMessage(ipMessHWND, WM_DROPFILES, (HDROP)&myDropFiles, 0);
```

Comment: just about what i was looking for.looks pretty complex.
Thx :)