# C# Drag and drop am image to a running application?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have an application that I did not make. This application lets images be drag and dropped onto it.

What I need to do is have a folder and any files that are added to it be dragged and dropped onto this application automatically, even if the app is minimized.

I have the filewatcher working I just do not know how to drop files onto an application, maybe by using its process ID?

If anyone knows how this might be possible please explain as I known it is pretty specific knowledge.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070740/drag-drop-using-sendmessage) post?